# Fill PHP array with contents of select multiple in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my view I have a form select multiple box where I add items using a select dropdown and a button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyC3N.png).

This is how the code of the select multiple box looks after adding 3 items to it.

```
<label for="nombresFamilia" class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <select multiple id="nombresFamilia" name="nombresFamilia[]" class="form-control">
       <option value="CABLES">CABLES</option>
       <option value="PCR">PCR</option>
       <option value="POSTES">POSTES</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

After submitting the form information, I want to save the items inside the select multiple into an array. This is the code I have in my controller.

```
function add()
{   
    .
    .
    .
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombresFamilia[]','NombresFamilia');

    if($this->form_validation->run())     
    {   
        .
        .
        .

        $params_familia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia[]');  
    }
}
```

However, when I try to var_dump the array

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($params_familia);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I get the message:  "Undefined variable: params_familia".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could pre-select the options of the select, do something like this
**VIEW**

```
<select name="nombresFamilia[]" class="" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="CABLES" selected="selected">CABLES</option>
  <option value="PCR" selected="selected">PCR</option>
  <option value="POSTES" selected="selected">POSTES</option>
</select>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$nombresFamilia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia');
// remove [] in nombresFamilia

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($params_familia);
echo "</pre>";
```

**PRODUCES**

```
Array
(
    [0] => CABLES
    [1] => PCR
    [2] => POSTES
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the selected options were added to the array. Now the problem is when the options are added to the selection box they look highlited and if the user clicks one of the options it will get deselected.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are named as arrays, dropdowns are not named as arrays . In Drop down or < select > only one value is returned which is selected. if you want to get value of the selected item. Name your select element as

```
<select multiple id="nombresFamilia" name="nombresFamilia" class="form-control">
   <option value="CABLES">CABLES</option>
   <option value="PCR">PCR</option>
   <option value="POSTES">POSTES</option>
</select>
```

and then get the value as

```
$params_familia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia');
```

if you want multiple selections then create checkboxes instead of dropdown as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="CABLES">Cables
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="PCR">PCR
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="POSTES">POSTES
```

and then get the values in your controller as

```
$params_familia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia[]');
```

**Edit as Per comment**

If you want to send all the values to the post , create array of checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="CABLES" selected>Cables
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="PCR" selected>PCR
<input type="checkbox" name="nombresFamilia[]" value="POSTES" selected>POSTES
```

and then post. In your Controller get these values by

```
$params_familia = $this->input->post('nombresFamilia[]');
```

Comment: Is there a way to add all the items inside the select miltiple into an array without them having to be selected? So when I click the submit button, all the items inside the box, even if not selected, would be save inside an array. Should I use a different item to do that instead of the multiple select box?

Comment: No need to use a select dropdown then. You can create an array of checkboxes and pre-select them by selected property and then send them to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form helper's multiselect function in your view like this in:

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );

echo form_multiselect('shirts[]', $options);
```

And then in controller, use the array like this:

```
print_r($this->input->post('shirts[]'));
```

Hope this helps.